# BULK COLLECT INTO: 'identifier' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am new to PLSQL and  making a couple of exercises using Bulk SQL.
I have the following package:

```
/*Update a commision with a new factor*/
FUNCTION commision_pct_update(p_job_id jobs.job_id%type, p_factor NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
```

and the following body:

```
FUNCTION commision_pct_update(p_job_id jobs.job_id%type, p_factor NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS 

BEGIN

SELECT job_id BULK COLLECT INTO v_employees_tab FROM employees;

FORALL i IN v_employees_tab.FIRST..v_employees_tab.LAST
  UPDATE employees SET commission_pct = (commission_pct * p_factor)
  WHERE commission_pct is not null AND job_id = p_job_id;
  RETURN SQL%ROWCOUNT;

END commision_pct_update;
```

I receive the following error in my Messages Log. (I'm using Oracle SQL Developer).

> Error(43,37): PLS-00201: identifier 'V_EMPLOYEES_TAB' must be declared

I don't know where or how to declare the identifier in the function.

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your variable (`v_employees_tab`) before the `BEGIN`, and indicate its type... for example:

```
FUNCTION commision_pct_update(p_job_id jobs.job_id%type, p_factor NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS 
   TYPE employees_type IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 
   v_employees_tab employees_type;
BEGIN
  [...]
```

That's a sample type of course, choose your correct one

Comment: Thanks, but how do i know the correct type is. I've edited my question with  an image of my table.

Comment: @XverhelstX I'm not really sure, you are doing some weird things here: selecting a type from a table which is different: you are passing a variable of the type from `jobs.jobs_id` (probably an integer) but selecting rows from `employee`. Then you are using `forall` but not using the `forall` variable (that'd be `i` in your case) in the loop. Check this article, it may point you on the direction of what you want to achieve: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html

Comment: *For what I understand* (which may not be right) from your code, you could just do with the `update` and not use `bulk collect` or `forall` at all, but again, I'm not quite sure

Comment: If what you want to do is update the commission on employees whose `job_id` is the passed in, by a factor, then **just**: `UPDATE employees SET commission_pct = (commission_pct * p_factor)
  WHERE commission_pct is not null AND job_id = p_job_id;` should do, no need for bulk collect or loop at all

Comment: Ah, that is correct! Now what if a `job_id` was not passed as a parameter and we need to update the commission on every employee, I would then probably use a bulk collect or loop?

Comment: No, you'd just remove the `AND job_id = p_job_id` from your `where` clause. Try not to convolute your code and do the easiest solution. Programmers sometimes get lost in "trying things" and forget how easy some things are :-)